# Dropbox C# API v2 List Team folder contents

Tags: c#, dropbox

I am trying to get the list of directories from the Dropbox API for the team members in business Dropbox.

The documentation seems to be somewhat unclear and frustratingly difficult to get contents. Therefore my code could off somewhat and hence why I am having issues. I have a development token for both Team and my admin user.

```
        using (var client = new DropboxTeamClient("my token"))
        {

            var teamInfo = await client.Team.GetInfoAsync();
            var teamName = teamInfo.Name;
            var numberOfUsers = teamInfo.NumProvisionedUsers;


            var memListResult = await client.Team.MembersListAsync();
            foreach (var m in memListResult.Members)
            {
                var accountId = m.Profile.AccountId;
                var email = m.Profile.Email;
                Console.WriteLine($"Id {accountId} - email is {email}");
            }

            var accId = memListResult.Members.First(x => x.Profile.Email.Equals("myEmail"))
                ?.Profile.AccountId;

            var memId = memListResult.Members.First(x => x.Profile.Email.Equals("myEmail"))
                ?.Profile.TeamMemberId;

            
            var dbx = client.AsAdmin(memId);

            

            try
            {
                var full = await dbx.Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", full.Name.DisplayName, full.Email);
                await ListRootFolder(dbx, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }



        }



  private async Task ListRootFolder(DropboxClient dbx)
  {
        var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty);
        //var tlist = await dbx.

        // show folders then files
        foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFolder))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D  {0}/", item.Name);
        }

        foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFile))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("F{0,8} {1}", item.AsFile.Size, item.Name);
        }
  }
```

No my issue is that I can only ever get what shows in my directory. So for example I have logged into the web browser into Dropbox I have three directories.

```
|
|- User Dir 'This is my home directory'
|- Team Dir 'This is a directory for the team'
|- Sample folder
```

The team has access to the Team dir and sample folder. All I would like to do is simply get the list of directories.

I must be doing something completely wrong; I have also tried the overrides for dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync I have set includeMountedFolders parameter to true and still only lists two files in my profile.

I have also tried using the user token instead of the Team token and setting asAdmin.

Apologies on the code is somewhat untidy; I just want to get it working before I refactor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to access your ["team space"](https://www.dropbox.com/help/business/team-space-overview). You need to explicitly specify this when calling the API. I recommend reading [the Namespace Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/namespace-guide), which covers this in detail.

The .NET SDK supports setting the `Dropbox-Api-Path-Root` header, via [`DropboxClient.WithPathRoot`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_DropboxClient_WithPathRoot.htm).

First, you can get the root info from [`GetCurrentAccountAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Users_Routes_UsersUserRoutes_GetCurrentAccountAsync.htm):

```
var accountInfo = await dbx.Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync();
Console.WriteLine(accountInfo.RootInfo.RootNamespaceId);
```

Then, you can access the team shared space by using [`DropboxClient.WithPathRoot`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_DropboxClient_WithPathRoot.htm) to set the `Dropbox-Api-Path-Root` header as desired, like:

```
dbx = dbx.WithPathRoot(new PathRoot.NamespaceId(accountInfo.RootInfo.RootNamespaceId));
var res = await this.client.Files.ListFolderAsync(path: "");
foreach (var entry in res.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);
}
```